# How could my two classes share the same JFrame or Frame?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

Alright, so my first class creates the Frame and also places a red rectangle in it which I can move. Now what i'm doing is, creating another class for a blue rectangle.
Now in my **attempt** i have created the second class and also extended the first class unto it; which doesn't seem to do the job.

**Summery:**
***What do I need to do so they share the same frame? Is there a method for this?***

***SOLVED VERSION***
*My Code(First Class):*  **EDITED**

```
        import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;



public class MyGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, y = 0, velx =0, vely =0, g = 0;
    private Color color;

    public MyGame() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x < 0) //stops us from going backwards past x = 0
        {
            velx = 0;
            x = 0;
        }

        if (y < 0) //stops us from going to the sky
        {
            vely = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

        if (y > 330) // stops us from going through the ground
        {
            vely = 0;
            y = 330;
        }

        x += velx;
        y += vely;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        {
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                vely = 1; // removing velx = 0 allows us to go vertically and horizontlly at the same time

            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                vely = -1; // same goes for here

            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

                velx = -1;
            }

            {
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

                    velx = 1;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        velx = 0;
        vely = 0;
    }




    public static void main (String arge[]){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new Incoming());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

(Second Class): **EDITED**

```
            import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;



public class Incoming extends MyGame {

private Color color;

int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

public Incoming() {
    color = Color.BLUE;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    super.actionPerformed(e);
    if (x < 0) //stops us from going backwards past x = 0
    {
        velx = 0;
        x = 0;
    }

    if (y < 0) //stops us from going to the sky
    {
        vely = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    if (y > 330) // stops us from going through the ground
    {
        vely = 0;
        y = 330;
    }

    x += velx;
    y += vely;
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    super.keyPressed(e);
    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    {
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            vely = 1; // removing velx = 0 allows us to go vertically and horizontlly at the same time

        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8) {
            vely = -1; // same goes for here

        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4) {
            vely = 0;
            velx = -1;
        }

        {
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6) {
                vely = 0;
                velx = 1;

            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    super.keyReleased(e);
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The problem is calling `super.paintComponent` in `Incoming` is rendering the `RED` rectangle.  A better solution would be to either use the component's color properties (maybe it's foreground) or supply a new color property you can change.  Your attempt at inheritance is slightly flawed in that you are duplicating a lot of functionality and data that already exists in the parent class...just saying.  Also, it would be better to use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over using `KeyListener`

Comment: How can I `use the component's color properties or supply a new color property you can change` and mind explaining what changing color property means and how would it fix this?

Comment: `setForeground` and `getForeground`. So, instead of `g.setColor(Color.BLUE);`, you would be able to use `g.setColor(getForeground());`

Comment: I just edited the second class. Seems like it didn't make a difference. Only the red rectangle is showing up. Perhaps I need to add the 'Incoming' class to the frame by `Incoming q = new Incoming........  f.add(q);' to the last part of the first class?

Comment: I would suggest that the call to `super.paintComponent` is still painting the red rectangle...take a look at the answers for some ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either take advantage of the color property support of the component or supply your own color property which could set and retrieved through the use of setters and getters

The following example simply uses the components existing `foreground` property...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GameExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameExample();
    }

    public GameExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                MyGame game = new MyGame();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(game);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
        int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0, g = 0;

        public MyGame() {
            t.start();
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
            setForeground(Color.RED);

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "up-pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "down-pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "left-pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "right-pressed");

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "up-released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "down-released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "left-released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "right-released");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("up-pressed", new YDelatAction(-1));
            am.put("down-pressed", new YDelatAction(1));
            am.put("left-pressed", new XDelatAction(-1));
            am.put("right-pressed", new XDelatAction(1));

            am.put("up-released", new YDelatAction(0));
            am.put("down-released", new YDelatAction(0));
            am.put("left-released", new XDelatAction(0));
            am.put("right-released", new XDelatAction(0));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(getForeground());
            g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (x < 0) //stops us from going backwards past x = 0
            {
                velx = 0;
                x = 0;
            }

            if (y < 0) //stops us from going to the sky
            {
                vely = 0;
                y = 0;
            }

            if (y > 330) // stops us from going through the ground
            {
                vely = 0;
                y = 330;
            }

            x += velx;
            y += vely;
            repaint();
        }

        public class XDelatAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int value;

            public XDelatAction(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                vely = 0;
                velx = value;
            }

        }

        public class YDelatAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int value;

            public YDelatAction(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                vely = value;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

This would allow you to create a new instance that use a different color by doing...

```
MyGame game = new MyGame();
game.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

Or you could create a new subclass using something like...

```
public class MyBlueGame extends MyGame {

    public MyBlueGame () {
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

Generally speaking, you should favour the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` as it provides more control over the level of focus required to generate key events and generally produces more re-usable and configurable code (IMHO)

**Updated**

So, based on you example code...

Each class is going to need it's own `color` property, which independent of the other, otherwise the inheritance is going to get in the way (and the parent will want to use the value of the child)

You will also need to change the `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` methods for the child class so that the two rectangles can move independently of each other.

This is not my preferred solution.  I would have a single game surface which was capable of rendering the state of the overall game (all the entities) and would provide a means by which the gaming elements could be added (and possibly removed) from the surface and some kind of controller that would be able to control the way in which those elements are updated...but that's just me...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameTest();
    }

    public GameTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Incoming());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

        Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
        int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0, g = 0;

        private Color color;

        public MyGame() {
            color = Color.RED;
            t.start();
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (x < 0) //stops us from going backwards past x = 0
            {
                velx = 0;
                x = 0;
            }

            if (y < 0) //stops us from going to the sky
            {
                vely = 0;
                y = 0;
            }

            if (y > 330) // stops us from going through the ground
            {
                vely = 0;
                y = 330;
            }

            x += velx;
            y += vely;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int code = e.getKeyCode();

            {
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    vely = 1; // removing velx = 0 allows us to go vertically and horizontlly at the same time

                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    vely = -1; // same goes for here

                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

                    velx = -1;
                }

                {
                    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

                        velx = 1;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            velx = 0;
            vely = 0;
        }

    }

    public class Incoming extends MyGame {

        private Color color;

        int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

        public Incoming() {
            color = Color.BLUE;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            super.actionPerformed(e);
            if (x < 0) //stops us from going backwards past x = 0
            {
                velx = 0;
                x = 0;
            }

            if (y < 0) //stops us from going to the sky
            {
                vely = 0;
                y = 0;
            }

            if (y > 330) // stops us from going through the ground
            {
                vely = 0;
                y = 330;
            }

            x += velx;
            y += vely;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyPressed(e);
            int code = e.getKeyCode();

            {
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2) {
                    vely = 1; // removing velx = 0 allows us to go vertically and horizontlly at the same time

                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8) {
                    vely = -1; // same goes for here

                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4) {
                    vely = 0;
                    velx = -1;
                }

                {
                    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6) {
                        vely = 0;
                        velx = 1;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyReleased(e);
            velx = 0;
            vely = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So that's the same thing but this time with KeyBindings, although they both run exactly the same. Why would it be useful for my current little game?

Comment: Which let me add, looks very confusing haha...oh nevermind now I see your explanation of why it's better

Comment: But, main reason I was using KeyListener was for the blue rectangle i was gonna have it move by itself which I would guess I can do with KeyBindings too. I'll work on it and see. Thank you

Comment: The answer to the question is, what is it that you are trying to achieve.  If you're trying to add new "entities" to the game canvas, then I would create a virtualized concept of the objects, which maintained information need to be able to paint them and simply add them to the same gaming surface...

Comment: I appreciate the help on the KeyBindings but I'm really not at that level yet. I don't understand 80% of what the code you gave me. Could we put the `setForeground` code on my current code? It feels like it would be better if I finish what I started and maybe learn KeyBindings from scratch at a later time.

Comment: Sure, call `setForeground` to change the color and the call `g.setColor(getForeground());` when you want to paint it.  I think you're going to have issues with your current concept of trying to use inheritance to achieve having and controlling multiple objects - IMHO

Comment: In my first class or second? (I'm guessing both)

Comment: The first class should control, well, everything. The second class should change the properties it needs, such as changing the color it wants to use.  The problem you now have is determining how to change the controlling keys...

Comment: If you basically take the key bindings out of my example, you have the core of what you need...

Comment: hmm well, I edited the code as you can see and seems like I didn't do everything. I'll take a look at your code again.

Comment: I think that's all? Is the blue rectangle not showing up because of my keyListeners or am I not Printing the colors correctly?

Comment: The problem is, your attempt to use inheritance is misplaced (IMHO), using the color properties in this manner is going to cause the parent class to use the same color properties as the child...

Comment: Can I use different color properties for the second class or is this some major flaw. And what's IMHO?

Comment: Are you guys brothers?

Comment: @BasicProgrammer Take a look at the update, you need to move one of the rectangles to see both (using either arrow or numpad keys)

Comment: @ryvantage haha no just happened to have similar names. Maybe this is why MadProgrammer is putting up with me.

Comment: @ryvantage No, where different psyche of the same person battling for control ;)

Comment: Split personalities. Got it. :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer what does `public GameTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }` do? Because it has an error on it

Comment: @BasicProgrammer It's sets the look and feel to compile with the current platform's look and feel...I hate Metal look and feel with a passion.  Also, it ensures that before I create or manipulate any UI elements, I'm running in the context of the EDT. Check out [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more details

Comment: Well, well brother. Seems like everything is up and going now. Thanks for all the efforts you put on this. It felt like we went on an adventure together...lol see you around

Answer (score 0):

i think all what you have to do is to set the colour as a parameter for your class `MyGame` , to add a field colour to your class.

```
private Color colour;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Colour);
        g.fillRect(x,y,70,40);
}


            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            MyGame s = new MyGame();
             s.setCoulor(Color.RED)   //  s.setCoulor(Color.BLUE)
            f.add(s);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(600,400);
            f.setVisible(true);
```